# Why doesn't this word macro make italics the first part of all lines containing a bracket?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with an index to a book I scanned.   Some lines of this index themselves refer to books, and those lines have brackets.   An example line could be:

The Rise and Fall of the Roman Empire (Norton and Associates)

So I search for lines with "(" in them, and then try to just make all prior words in that line to be italic.   It doesn't work - too many characters are made italic.  Here is my attempt:

```
Sub SelectPreBracketLetters(ByRef newDoc As Document)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lineText As String
    Dim lineLength As Integer
    Dim selectionStart As Integer
    Dim selectionEnd As Integer
    Dim bPos As Integer
    Dim ePos As Integer
    Dim myRange As Range
    
    For i = 1 To newDoc.Paragraphs.Count
        Set myRange = newDoc.Paragraphs(i).Range
        lineText = myRange.text
        lineLength = Len(lineText)
        If lineLength > 2 Then
            bPos = InStr(lineText, "(")
            If bPos > 2 Then
               ePos = InStr(lineText, ")")
               If ePos > bPos Then
                 ' MsgBox ("bpos is " & bPos & " and line is " & lineText)
                  myRange.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
                  myRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, bPos - 1
                  myRange.Font.Italic = wdToggle
               End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `myRange` represents the range of a paragraph. It is important to note that it does not correspond to the range returned by the Word `Find` method (you didn't use Find in the code).
- Change the count of chars for `MoveStart` and `MoveEnd` to fix the issues

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.MoveStart method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.movestart?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm157155438)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.MoveEnd method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.moveend?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm157155439)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
    If ePos > bPos Then
       myRange.MoveStart wdCharacter, bPos
       myRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, ePos - lineLength - 1
       myRange.Font.Italic = wdToggle
    End If
```